# Compute: Show that expected stopping times for $X_t = 2t + 3W_t$ and $Y_t = 6t + W_t$ to reach any any level $x>0$ are the same.

Tags: probability, stopping-times

I have this question from a textbook by ovidu calin, introduction to stochastic calculus. Now, from the textbook, I know that for a diffusion $X_t = \mu t + \sigma W_t$, $E[\tau] = \frac{x}{\mu}$ for the mean time to hit level $x>0$.

This seems to be at odds with the question. I want to say that the mean times are different for the 2 process and there is a typo in the question. Can anyone verify my claim?

Comment: The diffusion coefficient $\sigma$ should appear somewhere in your formula for $E(\tau)$, right?

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't. I quoted this result from the textbook. $E[\mu \tau + \sigma W_\tau] = x$. Then by using the optional stopping theorem on $W_t$, $E[\tau] = \frac{x}{\mu}$.

Comment: Ah right, the $\sigma$ disappears during the calculations... I see. Well, then you indeed just have to note that $2 \neq 6$ and you are done.